# SQL query to get multiple rows with different timestamps

Tags: mysql, sql, jpa, jpql

I am attempting get some data with their latest timestamps. sets of data have different timestamps which i need to get using their timestamps. for example:

| id | testcase_id | user | timestamp |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 | abbc | 2013-01-13 15:00:00 |
| 2 | 2 | pbbb | 2013-01-13 15:05:00 |
| 3 | 4 | dddd | 2013-01-13 15:05:00 |
| 4 | 4 | abbc | 2010-01-10 16:04:00 |

For `abbc` need to get row 1 which have latest `timestamp(2013-01-13 15:00:00)` and i need row 2 with `pbbb (2013-01-13 15:05:00)` and row 3 `dddd (2013-01-13 15:05:00)`. I have this timestamp data for each user in backend just need a proper query to fetch all those rows using timestamps.

Note: There could be multiple users with same timestamps, ex - if 10 users have same timestamp as abbc i will require all those users.

Answer (score 0):

JPQL is picky about the syntax it allows.  You may try using correlated subqueries here:

```
select e
from your_entity e
where e.timestamp = (select max(f.timestamp)
                     from your_entity f where f.user = e.user)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try CTE + analytical function row_number()

```sql
with t1 as (
  select id, testcase_id, user, timestamp, 
    row_number() over (partition by user order by timestamp desc) rno
  from your_table)
select select id, testcase_id, user, timestamp
from t1
where rno = 1
```

Comment: If the JPA and JPQL tags be accurate, then your query won't work.

Comment: You're right, workaround would be to create a view returning what OP wants.